# Problem parsing my date time in R Lubridate

Tags: r, lubridate

I am trying to parse my date time by it keep showing me "All formats failed to parse. No formats found."

These are the time I've been trying to parse and the code.

```r
datetime_clean <- c("4:10 pm Sept 18, 2021", "12:06 pm Sept 18, 2021", "9:42 am Sept 18, 2021")

datetime_parse <- parse_date_time(
  datetime_clean, "%I:%M %p %m/%d/%Y" 
)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We may use `as.POSIXct` from `base R`.  The month is in the format `%b` but with an extra letter long i.e. `%b` - denotes to abbreviated month name and it is the first three letter instead of four letter).  One option is to remove the 4th letter with `sub`, and use `%b` instead of `%m`

```
datetime_clean <- sub("([A-Za-z]{3})[a-z]", "\\1", datetime_clean)
as.POSIXct(datetime_clean, format = "%I:%M %p  %b %d, %Y")
```

-output

```
[1] "2021-09-18 16:10:00 EDT" "2021-09-18 12:06:00 EDT" "2021-09-18 09:42:00 EDT"
```

Or with `lubridate`

```
lubridate::parse_date_time(datetime_clean, '%I:%M %p %b %d, %Y')
```

-output

```
[1] "2021-09-18 16:10:00 UTC" "2021-09-18 12:06:00 UTC" "2021-09-18 09:42:00 UTC"
```

---

This may also be automatically parsed with `parsedate::parse_date` (from the original object without the `sub` modification)

```
parsedate::parse_date(datetime_clean)
[1] "2021-09-18 16:10:00 UTC" "2021-09-18 12:06:00 UTC" "2021-09-18 09:42:00 UTC"
```

#### data

```
datetime_clean <- c("4:10 pm Sept 18, 2021", "12:06 pm Sept 18, 2021" ,"9:42 am Sept 18, 2021")
```

Comment: Thank you very much it works. Can you explain to me why I did wrong and what is sub("([A-Za-z]{3})[a-z]", "\\1", datetime_clean) for?

Comment: @BillyCheongChunYen You used `%m/` and `%m` matches the two digit month, also the sep is not `/` as per your data i.e. a space is between `Sept` and `18`.  In addition, `Sep` is a legitimate abbreviation, So, I captured the 3 characters (`([A-Za-z]{3})` in a group (`(...)`) leaving the last character (`[a-z]`) out and in the replacement, specified the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group